# Using before_filter to check that an admin or a user is signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, before-filter

Is it possible to use Ruby on Rails' `before_filter` method to check that one of multiple things is true? Specifically, I am using Devise in which I have defined a user and an admin and I would like to ensure that whoever is accessing a specific controller is one or the other. I have looked for answers in documentation and SO and haven't had any luck.

Thanks, here are my versions (if it helps):

- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.6
- Devise 2.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible.  I'm hesitant to actually place this as an answer because it doesn't get any simpler than this.  I am assuming that you have an `admin?` method that returns true or false depending on the user's role.

```
before_filter :check_if_admin

protected

def check_if_admin
  if signed_in?
    raise 'Only admins allowed!' unless current_user.admin?
  else
    # or you can use the authenticate_user! devise provides to only allow signed_in users
    raise 'Please sign in!'
  end
end
```

Comment: You can add def check_if_admin to ApplicationHelper or probably an "AuthenticationHelper" and include the helper in the controller =)